# printing only a array with all data with firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase

printed result

```
["data1"]
["data1", "data2"]
["data1", "data2", "data3"] 
...
```

wanted result is only the last printed array with all data or just getting that last array would help me out

```
["data1", "data2", "data3"]
```

here is the code I use to get the data from firebase

```
 var dataArray = [String]()

     func fetchFirebaseData(){
            var datref: DatabaseReference!
            datref = Database.database().reference()

        datref.child("Data").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
                let data = SpeisekarteInfos(dictionary: dictionary)
                data.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                self.dataArray.append(data.Name!)

                print(self.dataArray)
            }

        }, withCancel: nil)


    }
```

Comment: your array after code execution will keep the last result, if you want print only that the remove the print from the observe closure

Answer (score 0):

You are observing `.childAdded` events, which will get called repeatedly, once for each entry in your database. I haven't used FireBase, but based on a little Googling it sounds like you should instead observe the `.value` event, and then refactor your code to expect all of them at once. Something like this:

```
 var dataArray: [String]?

 func fetchFirebaseData(){
        dataArray = []
        var datref: DatabaseReference!
        datref = Database.database().reference()

    datref.child("Data").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            if let dictionary = item as? [String: AnyObject]{
                let data = SpeisekarteInfos(dictionary: dictionary)
                data.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

                self.dataArray.append(data.Name!)
            }
        }
        print(self.dataArray)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

I'm doing some guesswork on the format of the data you get back from a .value call, so I'm not positive the above will work, but it should at least point you in the right direction.

Note that in my version we request everything at once with a .value observer, then loop through all the children returned, build them into an array, and only print the array once they're all returned.

From what I'm reading it looks like your `.value` observer will be called with all the elements every time the database is updated. If your database is dynamic this would not be a good approach.

Comment: unfortunately this is printing an empty array :(